# Teradata Geospatial - Multipolygon / polygon table creation

Tags: teradata, geospatial, polygon

Dears,
I have table with points for each id and  we need to create a multipolygon or polygon table in teradata with this data

```
table :
id    x-point   y -points 
100     10         25      
100     12         28
100    100        250 
101    110        125 
101    120        129
```

need to create a table in teradata for each id with multipolygon or polygon as geometry datatype

the output table should be

```
id     Geometry
100    multipolygon ( (10 25,12 28, 100 250) )
101    polygon(( 110 125, 120 129))
```

could any one please help me with the geospatial query to achieve this results

Answer (score 0):

There's an [AggGeom](https://docs.teradata.com/r/1drvVJp2FpjyrT5V3xs4dA/NVDhiBQ_CCndNEdA%7EObZ_A) table operator, which can be used to combine multiple rows with geospatial objects:

```
SELECT id, geom
FROM AggGeom
 ( ON 
    ( 
      SELECT new ST_Geometry('point(' || trim(x_point) ||' ' || trim (y_point) || ')')  as geom, id
      FROM vt
    ) 
   PARTITION BY id
   USING Operation('Union') 
 ) AS dt;
```

But this will return a MULTIPOINT, not a POLYGON, least of all a MULTIPOLYGON

`geom.st_ConvexHull()` is pobably the closest you can get.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, when i used with the data which contains 2million rows shows an error message: too much data passed into variable maximum length UDT instance . is there any other way to avoid this issue

Comment: ST_Geometry is limited to 16 MB, but per PARTITION column -> there must be a very large number of rows per id.

Comment: i will the check the data again,  could you also please suggest how to convert the multipoint to multipolygon or polygon. This Geospaital is very new for me . please suggest

Comment: As I wrote: `SELECT id, geom.st_ConvexHull()` will calculate the enveloping polygon, which might be fine for your limited example data, but not for a larger number of points. And in your data there's no order how the points get connected, e.g. `(10 25,12 28, 100 250)` is different from `(12 28, 10 25, 100 250)`. There are GIS packages for Python or R, which might be able to do what you want and they could be used either from Phyton/R connecting to Teradata or from Teradata using the `Script` or `ExecR` Table Operator fuctions.

Comment: I got limited knowledge in Geospatial, too :-)  You better approach someone in your organisation with experise in this area for *how to convert points to polygons*